# What is "Flynn's algorithm" relating to linked lists?

Tags: ds.algorithms

The other day, I came across an offhand mention of something called "Flynn's algorithm," which, as I gathered, had something to do with a linked list.  But that's all I was really able to discern.  Can anyone point me to a paper, or at least a web page that might further enlighten me?

Answer (score 2):

You might be thinking of [Floyd's algorithm for finding cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%27s_cycle-finding_algorithm#Tortoise_and_hare).  Given a singly linked list, it finds a cycle in the list (if one exists) in constant space and time linear in the size of the list.